# crash while performing a Rot13 in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, rot13

I feel as though this should be pretty fundamental but for some reason I'm stuck.

Here is what I have:

```
char *rot13(char *s)
{        
    char *p=s;        
    int upper;

    while (*p) {    
        upper=toupper(*p);              
        if (upper >='A' && upper <= 'M')
            *p+=13;  
        else if (upper>='N' && upper <= 'Z')
            *p-=13;  
        ++p;    
    }       
    return s;
}
```

I'm not a C guru but I'm relatively certain it's something trivial I just can't seem to pinpoint it. The error I get is once it hits either of the char modifiers (`*p+=13` or `*p-=13`) I get 'Unhandled Exception at ############: Access violation writing location #####"

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Be aware that your function won't work properly on systems using something like [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout). Numbers from 0 to 9 are ok to rely on being consecutive, but letters aren't.

Comment: The function looks pretty much correct. How did you call the function?

Comment: Are you passing the function a constant string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you perhaps calling `rot13()` with a (pointer to a) string literal as the actual argument?
String literals are read-only in C. Try something along

```
char foo[] = "YOUR STRING TO BE ROT13'D IN-PLACE.";

rot13 (foo);
```

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot.. I was calling it with    char *test = "TEST"; rot13(test). Its not what id consider a string literal but since your solution worked I'm confused? Can someone tell me why that fixed it?

Comment: It's because char **arrays** are not read-only by default (only when you declare them as `const foo[] = "...";`, while the C Standard explicitly makes writing to string literals *undefined behavior* (and exceptions are one type of allowed undefined behavior).

Comment: You might like to read the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), particularly section 6.

Answer (score 1):

Like pmg said, read the FAQ.  The following example might help guide you in the right direction.

Here is an example of using a pointer to char rather than a char array:

```
char *foo = malloc(36); // 35 + 1 for ending '\0'
strcpy(foo, "YOUR STRING TO BE ROT13'D IN-PLACE."); // requires #include <string.h>
printf("%s\n", rot13(foo));
```